# Pin-Locked Samsung with no debugging mode enabled (need data recovery)

Tags: lock-screens, data-recovery, usb-debugging

I do have two phones (both samsungs - first **A40** (SM-A405FN to be precise) and the second - **Galaxy S7** (SM-G930F)).

Both of those phones are PIN-locked by a PIN number I do not know. (The first one has 4-digit pin, the second one had 5-digit pin).

On both of those phones there is **no** debugging mode enabled. Both are not linked to samsung account (tho I know their google accounts credentials and I can log in to those if that matters).
And on both of those phones there is a data (photos mostly, but also some sentimental talks via SMS/WhatsApp).

I could skip recovering data from A40 (even tho recovering data from it would be neat), but I really need data from **Galaxy S7**.

I wondered if there is a way to access this data - once again, without debugging mode? Or is there any way I can enable debbuging mode (if it's enabled, I can easily do the remaining part).

I read about ADB and tried few things, but adb devices shows empty (unless in recovery mode I point "ADB Update", but even then I don't know how to proceed).

Comment: set a temporary screen lock pin from [Find My Mobile](https://findmymobile.samsung.com) or [Find My Device](https://google.com/android/devicemanager) (one of this should work). [bruteforcing](https://jumpespjump.blogspot.com/2013/06/online-brute-forcing-android-pin-lock.html) with microcontroller via usb-otg is another option which take a day for 4 digits but can take weeks for 5 digits

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221710