# Data recovery for Pin-Locked Samsung with no debugging mode enabled

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, data-recovery, usb-debugging

I do have phone Galaxy S7 (SM-G930F).

This phone is 5-digit PIN locked; which is lost.
There is no debugging mode enabled and it's not linked to samsung account (tho I know google accounts credentials and I can log in to those if that matters). And most crucial thing - on the phone (not on CARD) there is data (photos mostly, but also some sentimental talks via SMS/WhatsApp).

I wondered if there is a way to access this data - once again, without debugging mode? Or is there any way I can enable debbuging mode (if it's enabled, I can easily do the remaining part).

I read about ADB and tried few things, but adb devices shows empty (unless in recovery mode I point "ADB Update", but even then I don't know how to proceed).

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221707

Comment: Can't use Find My Device via samsung (those accounts <-> phone are not linked), and Find My Device via google does not unlock phone unless I erase data - but I do need this data.

Comment: @alecxs The solution you linked works for 4.4 and below. I have higher version, unluckily.

Comment: @alecxs when I try to "lock" my phone with this method, it says that there's native PIN on the phone already, so the new one will NOT be saved.
I justed tested on my other phone and it is how it works:
If I have no pin; with this method I can set pin.
If I have pin already (set on phone device, not by google account), I cannot set "second" pin code with google.

Comment: thx for update! it seems google "security" features becomes worse and useless. buy a Teensy and OTG hub